# Which number is larger?

Tags: binary, numbers

I'm not sure what is the correct answer to this question. For example, we have two numbers: '00' and '001'. Which number is larger?
If you can, please explain why.

Comment: 1 is greater than 0. This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this as binary

000 = 0

001 = 1

1 > 0 
so 
001 > 000

Below is a link on binary but in simple terms, it's just ascending powers of two from the right to the left starting with 2^0.

http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary

Comment: Thank you very much. You are the only person who responded to the case, rather than minus the question without knowing what to answer. I just wondered why in the photo gallery (written in PHP), by default the photo which signed as 001.png goes first on the list, and after it goes the photo signed as 00.png I thought everything should be the other way around. Perhaps in .php there is another order of priority.

Comment: The order you've described is based on file names which are strings. Strings have different comparison orders then binary numbers you've mentioned in question.

Comment: That should not happen. Try closing file explorer (or whatever you are using) and reopening it.